# Routing main domain to controller/action/id in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I would like to route www.domain.com/sections/view/1 to www.domain.com/..

the problem is i have no idea of how to pass through the id with the connect function class.

```
Router::connect('/',
    array(
        'controller' => 'sections'
        ,'action' => 'view'
        ,'id' => '1'
    ), 
    array(
        'id' => '1'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/sections/view/1', '/');
```

or

```
Router::connect('/sections/view/1', array(
    'controller' => 'something',
    'action' => 'whatever'
));
```

or

```
Router::connect('/sections/view/:id', array(
        'controller' => 'something',
        'action' => 'whatever',
    ),
    array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

(The first parameter is the one you're trying to control - the second is the one you want to send it to.)

**Update per comment (swaps the direction of the route):**

```
Router::connect('/', array(
    'controller' => 'something', 'action' => 'whatever', '1'
));
```

Comment: i've tried the options maybe it's my fault for not explaining.. when entering www.domain.com into my address bar i want it to route to section 1 (www.domain.com/sections/view/1) i don't want the "sections/view/1" to show.